# Error npm install when try react-paypal-express-checkout

Tags: node.js, reactjs, npm

i tried to install it using

```
npm i --save react-Paypal-express-checkout
```

but I get an error which says

```
npm ERR! code ERESOLVE npm ERR! ERESOLVE unable to resolve dependency tree npm ERR! npm ERR! While resolving: client@0.1.0 npm ERR! Found: react@17.0.2 npm ERR! node_modules/react npm ERR! react@"^17.0.2" from the root project npm ERR! npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency: npm ERR! peer react@"~0.14.8 || ^15.5.0" from react-paypal-express-checkout@1.0.5 npm ERR! node_modules/react-paypal-express-checkout npm ERR! react-paypal-express-checkout@"*" from the root project npm ERR! npm ERR! Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry npm ERR! this command.
```

It'll we great if someone help me How to fix it?

Comment: what is the error message?

Comment: the message is : 
npm ERR! code ERESOLVE
npm ERR! ERESOLVE unable to resolve dependency tree
npm ERR!
npm ERR! While resolving: client@0.1.0
npm ERR! Found: react@17.0.2
npm ERR! node_modules/react
npm ERR!   react@"^17.0.2" from the root project
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency:
npm ERR! peer react@"~0.14.8 || ^15.5.0" from react-paypal-express-checkout@1.0.5
npm ERR! node_modules/react-paypal-express-checkout
npm ERR!   react-paypal-express-checkout@"*" from the root project
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry
npm ERR! this command

Comment: had you run `npm install` to install npm dependencies?

Comment: yes, i do. i can install other package like, react-router-dom axios.. etc except react-paypal-express-checkout

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this command-

`npm install --save --legacy-peer-deps react-paypal-express-checkout`

> --legacy-peer-deps causes npm to completely ignore peerDependencies when building a package tree, as in npm versions 3 through 6. If a package cannot be installed because of overly strict peerDependencies that collide, it provides a way to move forward resolving the situation.

[See more...](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v7/using-npm/config#legacy-peer-deps)

PS: Also remember to use ONLY simple letters for package/library names when you're using them with NPM commands

Comment: still error, the message is: npm ERR! code E404
npm ERR! 404 Not Found - GET https://registry.npmjs.org/react-Paypal-express-checkout - Not found
npm ERR! 404
npm ERR! 404  'react-Paypal-express-checkout@*' is not in the npm registry.
npm ERR! 404 This package name is not valid, because
npm ERR! 404  1. name can no longer contain capital letters
npm ERR! 404
npm ERR! 404 Note that you can also install from a
npm ERR! 404 tarball, folder, http url, or git url.

Comment: @viiii there was a mistake in the command. We need to use only simple letters. I've edited my answer. Try again please

Comment: it's working now. you're really helpful thank you so much sir

Comment: glad to help. You can mark this as the correct answer